# How to create a pivot table uing python pandas with column entries pivoted to column heading and a new column for blank entries?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table in DataFrame taken from excel:

```
col A      ColB  colC  colD   
123451      a     w     p
123452      b     x     q
123453      c     y     r
123454      a     x     
123454      a     w     p
```

And I want something like this using pandas.pivot_table:

```
colC   p  q  r  "unassigned" "total"
 w     2  0  0      0           2
 x     0  1  0      1           2
 y     0  0  1      0           1
```

Comment: @jezrael, have made a slight change to the question, can you please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html) for first columns and then check missing values with [`isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isna.html) and aggregate by [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) for count by `sum` and total by [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html), last join togehter by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df1 = pd.crosstab(df.colC, df.colD)
print (df1)
colD  p  q  r
colC         
w     2  0  0
x     0  1  0
y     0  0  1

df2 = (df['colD'].isna()
                 .astype(int)
                 .groupby(df['colC'])
                 .agg([('unassigned','sum'),('total','size')]))
print (df2)
      unassigned  total
colC                   
w              0      2
x              1      2
y              0      1

df = df1.join(df2).reset_index()
print (df)
  colC  p  q  r  unassigned  total
0    w  2  0  0           0      2
1    x  0  1  0           1      2
2    y  0  0  1           0      1
```

Comment: Thank you @jezrael for the help! this works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace all the `None` with `'unassigned'`. Then use [crosstab](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html) to get respective counts. Use [sum](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html)  with proper axis for total count.

Following is the code for doing this

```
df1 = df[['colC', 'colD']].fillna('unassigned')
df1 = pd.crosstab(df1.colD, df1.colD)
df1['total'] = df1.sum(axis=1)
```

Following is the output for the code

```
D   p   q   r   unassigned  total
C                   
w   2   0   0    0           2
x   0   1   0    1           2
y   0   0   1    0           1
```

Comment: This would fail where other columns also have blank entries, it would change them too!

Comment: @sudoCoder we can slice data frame to use colC and colD only.

Comment: That may help, I see!